# Navision 5.0 Report Sort TotalFields

Tags: dynamics-nav, navision

I'm new to MS Dynamics NAV 5.0, I have created new Purchase Inventory Line Report using Report Designer. I have also group the line per item and total the quantity and the amount. What I trying to achieve is to sort the amount descending order.

This are my settings for the report.

**DataItem:** Purch. Inv Line

Properties:

GroupTotalFields = No.

TotalFields = Quantity, Amount

**Sections:**

Purch. Inv. Line, Header

Purch. Inv. Line, GroupFooter

Now how do I sort the **TotalField: Amount** by descending order?

Comment: Can you give a little more info regarding the data-items you have used so far? 

It's possible to sort a data item based on the keys that are available in the table. Or you can use a temp table like in report 111.

Comment: Thank you. I added details of the report.

Comment: Hi I have read the report 111 Customer Top 10 List. The report insert record to the Customer Amount table, but I don't know how does the report sorted records by amount descending. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort data by totals using report properties. But you could do this manually. Just iterate through inventory lines and save grouped and totaled results to temporary table variable. Then create new dataitem with base table called "Integer" and use it to print out the results in sections. You can find examples of this trick in many standard reports.

Comment: Thank you. gbierkens also suggest that. By examining the report 111, I was able to do want I want to display on my report.